# Adding and Removing Items From Flutter Lists Dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these two functions that should add the item onTap to the list, and then another one to delete the item. The first one (adding the item) works fine, but the delete one doesn't seem to delete anything. I suspect the issue is that the **counter** variable is not global, but for some reason it doesn't work fine when I add it globally (and I would need it to be). Here's the full code:

```
List<int> _totalPrice = [];
List<int> get totalPrice => _totalPrice;
```

**here is the add item function**

```
Future getTotal(item) async {
int counter = 0;

_totalPrice.add(int.parse(item));
_totalPrice.forEach((element) => counter += element);

print('LIST: $_totalPrice');
print('SUM: $counter');
return counter;
}
```

**here is the delete function that doesn't remove anything**

```
deleteSumItem(String item) {
_totalPrice.remove(item);
}
```

I think the issue is that the counter variable isn't global, I am not sure how to add it globally to change dynamically.

Comment: I feel like you example code above is only giving half the picture. Can you please post all of the code, including the widget code so we can see how you are trying to handle state management

Comment: Sure, I'll get back to you asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here your code shows that you are putting int in your `_totalPrice` list, but you are trying to remove the String from the list. It will not be found to be deleted.

So, you can change the data type of your list into String or you can write the below function to delete an item where the function only takes an int

```
deleteSumItem(int item) {
_totalPrice.remove(item);
}
```

Also you can remove an item by below line of code (If you have a custom type of data in your list):

```
_totalPrice.removeWhere((item) => item.price == '520')
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but the code is pretty complex, so I'll have to think how to proceed, it is probably unnecessarily complex, but that's on my part.